# maven-archetype-quickstart hangs with "Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml"

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

The quick start archetype doesn't seems to work. 
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -Dinteractivode=false -X

It hangs at :

...

[DEBUG]   (f) remoteArtifactRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@5da82c48
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
..

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a temporary outage. Works fine now.